# How to change the key of the message with mqtt source connect

Tags: apache-kafka, base64, mqtt, apache-kafka-connect

I have a java application sendind data into a mosquitto broker (mqtt), and using kafka connect, I'm sending this data from the mqtt broker to a kafka topic, but the problem is, always when the mqtt source connect sends the data, by default the key is always the name of the kafka topic, and I need to change it. I used SMT (Single Message Transforms), I could change the key, but it is encoded in base64, any idea how can I can convert and get only the value of the id?

my connector config with the transformation:

```
name=MqttSourceConnector
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.mqtt.MqttSourceConnector
mqtt.qos=1
tasks.max=2
mqtt.clean.session.enabled=true
mqtt.server.uri=tcp://mosquitto-server:1883
mqtt.connect.timeout.seconds=30
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
mqtt.topics=mqtt_topic
mqtt.keepalive.interval.seconds=60
kafka.topic=kafka_topic
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
transforms=createMap,createKey,extractInt
transforms.createMap.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.HoistField$Value
transforms.createMap.field=id
transforms.createKey.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey
transforms.createKey.fields=id
transforms.extractInt.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Value
transforms.extractInt.field=id
```

And what is getting into my kafka topic is:

```
Key { id: eyJpZCI6IlNCMDQiLCJ0ZW1wZXJhdHVyZSI6MjQuOTk2OTQyOTk0NDIyMTM4LCJodW1pZGl0eSI6MzkuNzUyNjQzNTk3MjcyMjYsInRpbWVzdGFtcCI6MTUzMjY4NTEzMTI2Nn0= }
Value { id: SB04, temperature: 24.996942994422138, humidity: 39.75264359727226, timestamp: 1532685131266 }
```

So, I just need the SB04 value to set as the key. Any idea?

Comment: Just use the decoder method of the Base64 class. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html

Comment: @Roger, Thanks for your answer. I am getting this data from the mqtt broker to the kafka topic using kafka connect, so the conversion should be done at the configuration, so I guess I am not be able to use a method to decode the base64 to set it to the key. How should I use this method so?

Comment: @robertoklein Hi. have you resolve the issue? I currently struggling with same problem. Need to decode base64, which comes to kafka from debezium connector